# Combining an until loop with a case in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, case

I'm trying to write a simple command line Cee-lo game in Ruby and I can't figure out why my loop won't work. Here is the code:

```
player_outcome = -10
player_roll = 500
until player_outcome >= 0 do 
    player_roll = [1 + rand(6), 1 + rand(6), 1 + rand(6)].to_a
    case player_roll
    when player_roll == [4, 5, 6]
        player_outcome = 100
    when player_roll == [1, 2, 3]
        player_outcome = 0
    when player_roll == [6, 6, 6]
        player_outcome = 99
    when player_roll == [5, 5, 5]
        player_outcome = 98
    when player_roll == [4, 4, 4]
        player_outcome = 97
    when player_roll == [3, 3, 3]
        player_outcome = 96
    when player_roll == [2, 2, 2]
        player_outcome = 95
    when player_roll == [1, 1, 1]
        player_outcome = 94
    when player_roll.uniq.length != 1 || 3
        player_outcome = player_roll.uniq
    end
end
```

This is my first attempt at programming and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean “won’t work”? What is the expected result and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

You're never hitting your numbers. Also, you don't need to #.to_a here:

`player_roll = [1 + rand(6), 1 + rand(6), 1 + rand(6)].to_a`

To trouble shoot, try reducing player roll to something like:

`player_roll = [1 + rand(3), 1 + rand(3)]`

Then comment out all your case statements for now, and add something like this to trace it:

`p player_roll == [2,3]; break if player_roll == [2,3]`

See how many iterations it will take just to reach that combination. You'll notice it will take quiet a few tries.

You can then build on this starting point to see how long things start to take, but yeah, this is just taking a long time to hit the combinations you've specified.

---

BTW, this statement does not appear to be correct:

`when player_roll.uniq.length != 1 || 3`

If you mean it does not equal 1 or 3, then you need to write it like:

`when player_roll.uniq.length != 1 || player_roll.uniq.length != 3`

The way you have it, it will evaluate to `3` if `player_roll.uniq.length != 1`